# Free Language Identifier Service?

Tags: web-services, google-translate

Do any of you guys know of a free online (or offline if it's in java) language identifier service? (I don't want a tool you use manually. I need a service, sice I have to do this identifying programatically.)

I've got a form and I'd like to figure out what language a user has written in.

Come to think of it, shouldn't this be doable through a Google thingy somehow? Since they detect page languages and all, and they're mostly open source...

Thanks for any help. Cheers!

[I added a "google-translate" tag since there isn't anything regarding text-recognition (there's image and voice but no text)]

Answer (score 1):

[Language Detection Library for Java](http://code.google.com/p/language-detection/) looks like the kind of thing you are looking for.

Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_identification for more links.

Answer (score 0):

[Language Detection API](http://detectlanguage.com) has free plan. You can pass text via HTTP POST and receive JSON result with detected languages and scores.